# keras image generator showing "Found 0 images belonging to 2 classes"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I was experimenting on the cats vs dogs dataset and I had downloaded and saved the dataset as a zip file as `/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/kagglecatsanddogs_3367a.zip`. The Code I'm working with is

```
import os
import zipfile
import random
import tensorflow as tf
import shutil
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from shutil import copyfile

path_cats_and_dogs = "/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/kagglecatsanddogs_3367a.zip"

local_zip = path_cats_and_dogs
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(local_zip, 'r')
zip_ref.extractall('/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir')
zip_ref.close()
try:
    shutil.rmtree("/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs")
except:
    pass
print(len(os.listdir('/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/PetImages/Cat/')))
print(len(os.listdir('/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/PetImages/Dog/')))

to_create = [
    '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs',
    '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/training',
    '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/testing',
    '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/training/cats',
    '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/training/dogs',
    '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/testing/cats',
    '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/testing/dogs'
]
for directory in to_create:
    try:
        os.mkdir(directory)
        print(directory, 'created')
    except:
        print(directory, 'failed')


def split_data(SOURCE, TRAINING, TESTING, SPLIT_SIZE):
    all_files = []
    for file_name in os.listdir(SOURCE):
        file_path = SOURCE + file_name

        if os.path.getsize(file_path):
            all_files.append(file_name)
        else:
            print('{} is zero length, so ignoring'.format(file_name))
    n_files = len(all_files)
    split_point = int(n_files * SPLIT_SIZE)

    shuffled = random.sample(all_files, n_files)

    train_set = shuffled[:split_point]
    test_set = shuffled[split_point:]

    for file_name in train_set:
        copyfile(SOURCE + file_name, TRAINING + file_name)

    for file_name in test_set:
        copyfile(SOURCE + file_name, TESTING + file_name)

    CAT_SOURCE_DIR = r'/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/PetImages/Cat/'
    TRAINING_CATS_DIR = r'/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/training/cats/'
    TESTING_CATS_DIR = r'/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/testing/cats/'

    DOG_SOURCE_DIR = r'/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/PetImages/Dog/'
    TRAINING_DOGS_DIR = r'/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/training/dogs/'
    TESTING_DOGS_DIR = r'/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/testing/dogs/'

    split_size = 0.9
    split_data(CAT_SOURCE_DIR, TRAINING_CATS_DIR, TESTING_CATS_DIR, split_size)
    split_data(DOG_SOURCE_DIR, TRAINING_DOGS_DIR, TESTING_DOGS_DIR, split_size)


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

TRAINING_DIR = '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/training'
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TRAINING_DIR,
    batch_size=10,
    class_mode='binary',
    target_size=(150, 150)
)
VALIDATION_DIR = '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/testing'
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    VALIDATION_DIR,
    batch_size=10,
    class_mode='binary',
    target_size=(150, 150)
)

model.fit(train_generator, epochs=2, verbose=1, validation_data=validation_generator)
```

When I manually look into the `tempdir` directory is can see the following

1. cats-v-dogs
   1.1 testing
   1.1.1 cats // this directories are empty
   1.1.2 dogs // this directories are empty
   1.2 training
   1.2.1 cats // this directories are empty
   1.2.2 dogs // this directories are empty
2. PetImages
   2.1 Cat // this has all the cat images
   2.2 Dog // this has all the dog images
3. kagglecatsanddogs_3376a.zip
4. MSR-LA - 3467.docx
5. readme[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMLG5.png).txt
   [/PetImages/Cat and /PetImages/Dog contain the actual images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMLG5.png)

From what I've leaned the `ImageDataGenerator` API looks for directories that contain directories that contain the actual image. But when I run the above code I get the following errors

```
Found 0 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 0 images belonging to 2 classes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/cats_vs_dogs.py", line 107, in <module>
    model.fit(train_generator, epochs=2, verbose=1, validation_data=validation_generator)
  File "/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1063, in fit
    steps_per_execution=self._steps_per_execution)
  File "/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 1117, in __init__
    model=model)
  File "/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 916, in __init__
    **kwargs)
  File "/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 786, in __init__
    peek, x = self._peek_and_restore(x)
  File "/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 920, in _peek_and_restore
    return x[0], x
  File "/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 57, in __getitem__
    length=len(self)))
ValueError: Asked to retrieve element 0, but the Sequence has length 0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could someone help me in figuring out where the error lies what I can do to fix them
edit- added the contents of the directories

Comment: What is inside the folder pointed to by TRAINING_DIR? and inside each subfolder?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I have edited the question to show the directory structure and I have also added an image. Thanks!

Comment: Then the problem is that the dogs and cats folders are empty, that is exactly where all the images of dog/cat each should be

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to have answered my own question but error was how the `split_data` function was called. Due to an error in the indentation, the function was called almost recursively. The corrected code now stands as

```
import os
import shutil
import zipfile
from random import shuffle

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

path_cats_and_dogs = "/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/kagglecatsanddogs_3367a.zip"

local_zip = path_cats_and_dogs
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(local_zip, 'r')
zip_ref.extractall('/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir')
zip_ref.close()
try:
    shutil.rmtree("/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs")
except:
    pass
print(len(os.listdir('/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/PetImages/Cat/')))
print(len(os.listdir('/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/PetImages/Dog/')))

to_create = [
    '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs',
    '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/training',
    '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/testing',
    '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/training/cats',
    '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/training/dogs',
    '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/testing/cats',
    '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/testing/dogs'
]
for directory in to_create:
    try:
        os.mkdir(directory)
        print(directory, 'created')
    except:
        print(directory, 'failed')


def split_data(SOURCE, TRAINING, TESTING, SPLIT_SIZE):
    # YOUR CODE STARTS HERE
    all_images = os.listdir(SOURCE)
    shuffle(all_images)
    splitting_index = round(SPLIT_SIZE*len(all_images))
    train_images = all_images[:splitting_index]
    test_images = all_images[splitting_index:]

    for img in train_images:
        src = os.path.join(SOURCE, img)
        dst = os.path.join(TRAINING, img)
        if os.path.getsize(src) <= 0:
            print(img+" is zero length, so ignoring!!")
        else:
            shutil.copyfile(src, dst)

    for img in test_images:
        src = os.path.join(SOURCE, img)
        dst = os.path.join(TESTING, img)
        if os.path.getsize(src) <= 0:
            print(img+" is zero length, so ignoring!!")
        else:
            shutil.copyfile(src, dst)

CAT_SOURCE_DIR = '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/PetImages/Cat/'
TRAINING_CATS_DIR = '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/training/cats/'
TESTING_CATS_DIR = '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/testing/cats/'

DOG_SOURCE_DIR = '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/PetImages/Dog/'
TRAINING_DOGS_DIR = '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/training/dogs/'
TESTING_DOGS_DIR = '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/testing/dogs/'

split_size = 0.9
split_data(CAT_SOURCE_DIR, TRAINING_CATS_DIR, TESTING_CATS_DIR, split_size)
split_data(DOG_SOURCE_DIR, TRAINING_DOGS_DIR, TESTING_DOGS_DIR, split_size)


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

TRAINING_DIR = '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/training'
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TRAINING_DIR,
    batch_size=10,
    class_mode='binary',
    target_size=(150, 150)
)
VALIDATION_DIR = '/Users/supreethrao/PycharmProjects/LearnTensorFlow/tempdir/cats-v-dogs/testing'
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    VALIDATION_DIR,
    batch_size=10,
    class_mode='binary',
    target_size=(150, 150)
)

model.fit(train_generator, epochs=2, verbose=1, validation_data=validation_generator)
```